# Unity wrong instance of class is being called on click. Creating my own input manager.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, unity-ui

I am making my own InputManager to remap keys during the game.

**The problem is that I have assigned class to each of shortcut's parent and when the button is pressed on the debugger I can see data from another key.
And only this key keeps being changed over and over again.**

Here is my example: *Up* is the parent of button, *UpS* is button being pressed which call the method from it's parent. In each parent-children it is set the same way as there. 
[image: Hierarchy with the inspector - assignment of key]
[image]

On button press I call

```
public void ToggleChangeButtonPannel(Button button)
{
    this.ActionText.text = Description;
    this.CurrentKeyText.text = Name;

    if (Panel.enabled)
    {
        Panel.enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Panel.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

And at update I check if panel is visible. I think the problem might be with the specification of Update() method. Does it work on every instance in parallel?
If that is the case - is it possible to use *Input.anyKeyDown* outside the Update() method?

```
private void Update()
{
    if (!Panel.enabled)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (Input.anyKeyDown)
    {
        var currentKey = Key;
        try
        {
            var newKey = (KeyCode)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), Input.inputString.ToUpper());

            if (Shortcuts.TryChangeKeyCode(currentKey, newKey))
            {
                RenameButtons(newKey);
            }
            else
            {
                //Error message handling
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //Error message handling
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as I thought with Update() method. I have fixed it by using caroutine.

```
public void ToggleChangeButtonPannel(Button button)
{
    ActionText.text = Description;
    CurrentKeyText.text = Name;

    if (Panel.enabled)
    {
        Panel.enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Panel.enabled = true;
        StartCoroutine(KeyRoutine());
    }
    EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
}


IEnumerator KeyRoutine()
{
    while (!Panel.enabled || !Input.anyKeyDown)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    try
    {
        var newKey = (KeyCode)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), Input.inputString.ToUpper());
        if (Shortcuts.TryChangeKeyCode(Key, newKey))
        {
            RenameButtons(newKey);
            Key = newKey;
            Panel.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
             StartCoroutine(RemoveAfterSeconds(3, Panel));
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        StartCoroutine(RemoveAfterSeconds(3, Panel));
    }
}
```